# beautifulsoup - Multiple for for multiple values and how to save them into JSON

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm using selenium + beautifulsoup.

I need to store the data I find, I initially thought of array, but now I'm thinking json might be better, but I have no idea how to write it from what I grab.

```
        doc = []
        spec = []
        for i in range(1, 2):
            driver.get('https://local.data/doctors/%d' % i)
            driver.execute_script("$('mark').remove()")
            time.sleep(3)
            html = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            for doctors in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"data-ga-label": "profile_name"}):
                doc.append(doctors.text)
            for specialties in soup.find_all('p', attrs={"class": "specialities"}):
                spec.append(specialties.text.strip())
            for cities in soup.find_all('span', class_="city"):
                c = cities.text.split('-')[0].replace(":", "")
                print(c)
```

Instead of writing an array for it, I'd like to write a single json entry for all the values I found on the `doctor`, `specialties` and `cities`.

So that would be something like:

```
{
 doctor_name: "john hopkins",
 specialty: "surgeon",
 city: "new york"
}
```

for each of the values I grab with beautifulsoup.

How can I do that?

Comment: why are you not just using selenium?  you dont need BeatifulSoup to parse

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work. But still, its not the proper way for doing what you have asked. It would be better if you share the html construct of the page you want to scrape.

```
docs = [doctors.text for doctors in soup.find_all('a', attrs={"data-ga-label": "profile_name"})]
spec = [specialties.text.strip() for specialties in soup.find_all('p', attrs={"class": "specialities"})]
cities = [cities.text.split('-')[0].replace(":", "") for cities in soup.find_all('span', class_="city")]
doc_profiles = []
for index, data in docs:
    doc_profile ={'doctor_name': data,
                  'specialty': spec[index],
                  '': cities[index]}
    doc_profiles.append(doc_profile)
```

Sharing your challenge properly with supportive data will help us to help you better.